# Automating web based Qlikview using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, export, qlikview

I am pretty new to this selenium module in python.
I am trying to automate web based qlikview with selenium and have somewhat managed to do it but facing one problem.

The problem is:

I am able to change tabs and apply filter and export data from the qlickview by typing in the commands in the pycharm console (command prompt) but when i put together the commands and run the code, the code is not executing in the desired manner?
Can somebody help me regarding this?

```py
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
link = 'some link' 
driver.get(link) 
driver.implicitly_wait(15) 
click_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("path").click() 
driver.implicitly_wait(2) 
click_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').click()
```

It will be very appreciated. Please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code you used and read the Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
link = 'some link'
driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
click_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("path").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
click_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').click()

Comment: it runs perfectly in the pycharm console

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you to read asking [guidelines of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Comments may or may not be shown initially, and are usually shown in order of votes. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place, the question. Describe *exactly* what the problem is, "is not executing in the desired manner" is too vague. What happens, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?